# How can i display record owner's SmallPhotoUrl in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, url

Is there any way in Apex to fetch custom object's record Owner's(not CreatedBy) SmallPhotoUrl to be displayed in LWC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get that using a wired apex method.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static string getSmallPhotoUrl(String userId){
    return [SELECT u.SmallPhotoUrl From User u where u.id=:userId].SmallPhotoUrl;
}
```

Comment: thanks Rahul. It worked well.

Comment: Most Welcome!!!